# CFML decrypt string from database on the fly

Tags: sql-server, encryption, coldfusion, cfml

I have the following script that tries to select some items from my database and decrypt the encrypted ones, the problem is the encryption key is made unique with a changing `company_id` I have in my table:

```
<cfset request.ek = "password">
<!-- <cfset encKey = encrypt(request.ek, company_id)> -->
<!-- <cfset decrypted = decrypt(urldecode(arguments.mystring), encKey)> -->

<cfquery name="header" datasource="MyDB">
    SELECT TOP 10
        ID,
        company_id,
        encString
    FROM 
        dbo.[TableName];
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>ID|company_id|encString<br></cfoutput>

<cfloop query="header">
    <cfoutput>#ID#|#company_id#|#decrypt(urldecode(encString, encrypt(request.eq, company_id)))#<br></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

I get this error:

```
Parameter validation error for the DECRYPT function.
The function accepts 2 to 6 parameters.
```

EDIT.
Thanks Scott Stroz, I really messed with the parentheses. My code should be:

```
<cfset request.ek = "password">
<!-- <cfset encKey = encrypt(request.ek, company_id)> -->
<!-- <cfset decrypted = decrypt(urldecode(arguments.mystring), encKey)> -->

<cfquery name="header" datasource="MyDB">
    SELECT TOP 10
        ID,
        company_id,
        encString
    FROM 
        dbo.[TableName];
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>ID|company_id|encString<br></cfoutput>

<cfloop query="header">
    <cfoutput>#ID#|#company_id#|#decrypt(urldecode(encString), encrypt(request.eq, company_id))#<br></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: As an aside, if this data is important, you really should switch to a stronger algorithm. [`cfmx_compat` is the least secure of the available algorithms](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c2f.html) and only included for backward compatibility with older versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to decrypt() near the end of your code sample only has 1 argument. Looks like it might be a problem with your parentheses.

It looks like:

```
decrypt(urldecode(encString, encrypt(request.eq, company_id)))
```

might need to be:

```
decrypt(urldecode(encString), encrypt(request.eq, company_id))
```

assuming

1. that you encrypted string in the database was then url encoded before insert.
2. you encrypted the string with a key of ( `request.eq` encrypted with a key of `company_id` ).

Comment: How come? I open 3 parentheses and close 3...ohhh, got it.